# How to keep only the first word in a line using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to keep only the first word of each line within Notepad ++. For an example, please consider the situation where I have these lines

aleag greats broa
abro gdert gfherr httowpw
asteruso dgheur graterf

Want I would like have left is this
aleag
abro
asteruso

How do I do this? Either using notepad++ or something else.

Comment: Notepad++ allows regular expression to find match [ use CTRL+F ]. You can write regular expression to match everything after face space character and replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 8):

I've only just looked at a [reference sheet](http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad/), so there's probably a better way to do this, but you could do something like this with the Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>):

**Find**: `([0-9a-zA-Z]*)([0-9a-zA-Z ]*$)`
**Replace**: `\1`

The way I read it is basically:
`[0-9a-zA-Z]` : match an alphanumeric character
`*`  : keep matching them
`[0-9a-zA-Z ]`  : match an alphanumeric character or a space
`$`  : match the end of the line
`()` : "holds" a match in a variable. The first `()` holds a match in `\1`, the second in `\2` (which we don't need).

Since the first `()` is "holding" the match you want, that will be what you are replacing the text with. It does this for each line if you hit **Replace All**.

[image: wordpad++ find replace]

Answer (score 7):

A similar solution to the one Louis suggested is to again use Regular expression search within Notepad++, with the search parameter:

```
(^.+?)\s.*$
```

And replace with:

```
\1
```

The advantage/difference of this version over Louis' one is that it will also match first words like `Apostrophy's` or `Colons:` or `Hyphen-ated` where there are non alphanumeric characters.

This matches everything from the start of each line (the `^` symbol means start of line).
It finds at least one character (`.+?` is non-greedy match one or more characters) stopping as soon as it finds a blank (`\s` is blank/space).
It then carries on matching everything else in the line (`.*` is match zero or more characters), up to the end of the line (`$` is end of line).

The `\1` will then only keep the section matched within the brackets, I.E. everything before the first space in the line.

N.B. make sure the `. matches newline` checkbox is unticked, or you will only get the first word in the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't know any languages to program in, you can do this in Excel

Paste each line into Column A.

Then, in column B, paste

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not good with programming languages sir,so something else means any program that i can download and use to do what i need to be done

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler solution is to use  `.*`

Just open Notepad++, Choose regular expression's in search and replace, enter the below and then click replace all:

```
Find:  .*
```

Note that, the is a space in front of the dot and that replace is blank.

[image]